# HTML forms post to 3 locations

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-sheets, salesforce

I am a bit new to coding. I have made a HTML form and want to post it to three different locations. One is an **email**, other is a **salesforce server** and third is a **google spreadsheet**. I have tried searching it on google it but didnt get the fruitful answer. Is there any way that I can achieve that process.

Any valid resource will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want the same post request sent to all three locations?

Comment: yes @WillReese it will be the same request

Answer (score 2):

You can successfully do this by using the ajax post call in jQuery. Below is a sample:

```
$('#some_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Post to Email
    $.post('/some/url/for/email', function(data) {
        // Handle the response
    }
    // Post to salesforce
    $.post('/some/url/for/salesforce', function(data) {
        // Handle the response
    }
    // Post to google spreadsheet
    $.post('/some/url/for/google', function(data) {
        // Handle the response
    }
    window.location.href = '/some/final/place/after/submission';
}
```

See more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen. I will try to work over these lines. I am sorry I am just familiar with HTML that is why couldnot figure out the way to handle this..

Comment: No problem at all! That is why we are here to help on stack overflow :) just be sure to select an answer as your solution when finished.